# chmod adding only write permission for user

Tags: linux, ubuntu, chmod, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am new to linux. I learnt about chmod command, and was trying to do some practice. There is a file named "a". Initially this file has no permissions for user, group, and other user. I tried `chmod +r a` and it added read permission for everyone. Then I tried `chmod +x a`, and it added execute permission for everyone.

But when I tried `chmod +w a`, it added write permission for only user, group and other user were not granted write permission.

Also, when Im using `chmod 777 a`, read, write and execute permission are granted for evveryone.

I'm not able to understand why `chmod +w a` give write permission to only user who owned the file.

[image: I have also attached screenshot for reference]

Comment: I believe the syntax should be `chmod a+w a`.  Where the first `a` means "all" and the second `a` is the name of your file.  If you don't have the first `a`, then `a` is assumed with the caveat that bits that are set in the umask are not affected.

Comment: Thanks @Stewart, I got it now. When I tried with different file name, chmod +w b, it is working as expected.